# How to bake a normal map on to a mesh

Tags: texture-baking, baking, normal-map, retopology

I have made my retopology model and transfer the sculpting details trough a normal map node and now I want to add materials to my new low poly mesh. My fear is that if I move or change the previous unwrap to create the final material for my mesh the previous baked normal map material will get distorted.

So my question is how do I add material to my new low poly mesh (with normal map included) if there is an active normal map already?

Is there a way to permanently bake the details obtained to a normal map material node so that I can continue working on textures?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to unwrap again? If so, you can create a second UV map in the Object Data panel, use the new UV map for the new texture?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.  Can you be more specific please. I did create a second UV map as you said but to it seems that to activate this second UV I need to deactivate the first? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I attached a picture in the post so you can see what am I talking about.

Comment: From what I understand you want to create a second Image Texture that you'll plug into the Base Color of the Principled BSDF? You don't need to create a second UV Map, you can use the same for both the normal map and the texture that you'll paint. If you really need to use a second UV map, then create an Input > UV Map node, in this node select the second UV map, and plug it into the Image Texture

Comment: You are right. I didn't need to create a second UV map. I added the texture with its respective normal map and the I added the sculpt mapping to displacement and it works. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change the existing unwrap, use the same UV map for the texture that you want to paint.